# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/hibayoussef/Riaaaa-website.git'

Tags: git, github

I am trying to upload the project to GitHub.

And I followed these steps:

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/hibayoussef/Riaaaa-website.git
git push -u origin main
```

But I got this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/hibayoussef/Ria-website.git'
```

What is the cause and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

in most cases the problem is because remote branch (server) has recent modifications that your local branch doesn't have. you need to update (git pull) your local branch before push the modifications.

do a local commit, then pull modifications and then push those.

(the first line only if you doenst have configured remote branch)

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/hibayoussef/Riaaaa-website.git

$ git add .;git commit -m "commit before update"
$ git pull
```

then resolve problems who appears after the update then commit and push

alternative solution for the same problem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371329/error-failed-to-push-some-refs

if the remote branch doens't have modifications yet verify if your SSH key are configured correctly.